# Get all records which count is more than specific number

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

So here is my example.

I have a list of blog posts that belongs to multiple authors. I want to get all blog posts that are written by the author who has more than 3 blog posts.

POSTS table

```
id | author_id | post_title | post_body
1  |    1      |  ...       | ...
2  |    1      |  ...       | ...
3  |    1      |  ...       | ...
4  |    2      |  ...       | ...
5  |    3      |  ...       | ...
6  |    4      |  ...       | ...
7  |    4      |  ...       | ...
8  |    4      |  ...       | ...
9  |    5      |  ...       | ...
```

So, I want to get this as a result:

```
id | author_id | post_title | post_body
1  |    1      |  ...       | ...
2  |    1      |  ...       | ...
3  |    1      |  ...       | ...
6  |    4      |  ...       | ...
7  |    4      |  ...       | ...
8  |    4      |  ...       | ...
```

How I can write this in one eloquent query?

Comment: do you have any relationships setup with models?

Comment: yes, i have relationships with author model.

Comment: does author have a relationship back to posts?

Comment: yes, it has. What would be the best solution to make this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to double check if this has to be nested differently, but something like this seems like it would do the trick:

```
Post::has('user.posts', '>', 3)->get()
```

Trying to say get Posts that have a user which has a number of posts greater than 3.

If that nesting doesn't work it would be something like:

```
Post::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
    $q->has('posts', '>', 3);
})->get();
```

Updated:

```
Post::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('posts', function ($q) {
        $q->where('status', 'published');
    }, '>', 3);
})->get():
```

Though see if this works (not sure):

```
Post::whereHas('users.posts', function ($q) {
    $q->where('status', 'published');
}, '>', 3)->get();
```

Comment: This is perfect, but I have one more problem on how to make this work with additional parameters? For example filter by a given date period? Like how to make work this at the last point of the query? when I filtered everything by other parameters.

Comment: filter what by what parameter, you have to be specific as it will depend upon where the conditions/filters go

Comment: @django11 if you want to filter posts further just add the wheres before the call to `get`

Comment: I don't know how to make this part work:  "$q->has('posts', '>', 3);" I want to check if user has more than 3 posts with status published. Now it just checks if the user has more than 3 posts.

Comment: @django11 that would require you using a `whereHas` instead of `has` for the 'posts' check, updated

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by author_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 3
order by cnt desc, author_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can/want to use SQL, you can do this:

```
select *
from POSTS
where author_id in 
(
  -- authors with more than 3 posts
  select author_id
  from POSTS
  group by author_id
  having count(*) > 3
)
```